# PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService::SetExpressCheckout() returns null response object

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using Yii to build an application that requires payments through PayPal. After a lot of digging, I found that ExpressCheckout is the method to use. The code below worked fine some time ago (some (?) weeks ago, I suppose before PayPal rolling out their new developer platform), using version 1.2.95 of the PHP SDK. Now, using the latest version v.2.2.98, the code fails.

```
require_once(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.libraries.paypal') . '/PPBootStrap.php');
$logger = new PPLoggingManager('SetExpressCheckout');

$PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
$PaymentDetails->OrderTotal =  $PaymentDetails->ItemTotal =
  new BasicAmountType('USD', $subscription->price);
$PaymentDetails->PaymentAction = "Sale";
$PaymentDetails->OrderDescription = $subscription->description;

$setECReqDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
$setECReqDetails->PaymentDetails[0] = $PaymentDetails;
$setECReqDetails->CancelURL = 'someCancelUrl';
$setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = 'someReturnUrl';

$setECReqType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
$setECReqType->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $setECReqDetails;

$setECReq = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
$setECReq->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $setECReqType;

$paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();

$ok = TRUE;
try {
  $setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);
  if($setECResponse && strtoupper($setECResponse->Ack) =='SUCCESS') {
    $token = $setECResponse->Token;
    // Redirect to paypal.com here
    $this->redirect(
      'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . $token);
  }
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
  Yii::trace(__METHOD__ . ': Exception while interacting with PayPal API, error: '
    . $ex->getMessage());
  $ok = FALSE;
}
```

The offending line is:

```
$setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);
```

In PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService::SetExpressCheckout(), these two lines:

```
$resp = $this->call('PayPalAPIAA', 'SetExpressCheckout', $setExpressCheckoutReq, $apiCredential);
$ret->init(PPUtils::xmlToArray($resp));
```

are the issue. `$resp` is null, so the next line fails at the `PPUtils::xmlToArray($resp)` method call.

Obviously, either I'm missing something here, or PayPal does something wrong.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, the cause of the issue was that the `service.EndPoint.PayPalAPI` parameter was not defined in `sdk_config.ini`. For some reason that I don't recall, this parameter was deleted from the working config file from the previous version.

Now, the express checkout method works fine, even with the latest 2.3.100 version of the API.